# How to copy files from Azure blob container directly to Azure disk

Tags: azure, azcopy

I have some files in Azure blob containers that I'd like to copy directly to an Azure disk when the disk is created. I did not think it was possible to copy files to a disk that is not attached to a VM, so I spun up an Azure VM and attached the disk. However, I can't figure out how I can use the Azure CLI to copy some files from a blob container to this disk (both are in the same storage account).

I was thinking it would look something along the lines of [this](https://az%20vm%20disk%20attach%20-g%20myResourceGroup%20--vm-name%20myVM%20--name%20$diskId) from the Azure docs, but I have a disk, not a file share.

Answer (score 1):

You can run [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404) on the VM you have attached the disk to, to copy the files from blob to the disk.